# Transpose table by group

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transpose a table to make it more workable. Currently, the table has data for multiple variables, i.e. all 50 states with a set of distance bands for each state such that it looks like:

```
Alabama, 0-250, value;
Alabama, 250-500, value;
Alabam...
Alaska, 0-250, value;
...
```

I'd like to change the table so that each state is a column and each distance band is represented as a second axis and the table is filled with values.

```
State Alabama Alaska ...
0-250   value . value ...
250-500 value . value ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table.

Put the states in the columns, the distance bands as rows and the values in values:

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much. I need to start using pivot tables more..